# Subsonic support for Oracle ODP.NET?

Tags: oracle, subsonic, odp.net

I'm new to Subsonic and I work primarily with Oracle databases. Can subsonic be used against an Oracle database and does it support the use of Oracle's ODP.NET data provider.

If yes, can you point me to a good example?

Thanks in advance.
Scott

Answer (score 2):

Marve is a little misleading.  Subsonic can be used with Oracle but SubSonic 2.x actually uses `System.Data.OracleClient`.   Subsonic 3.0 does not have any .tt files for Oracle yet as no one has stepped forward to do it.  I have been using Subsonic 2.2 with Oracle for months now and find that it works very well.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  I wasn't aware that no Oracle templates are in place.

Answer (score 0):

SubSonic does indeed [work with Oracle](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Supported_Databases).  Go [here](http://www.davesquared.net/2007/11/getting-subsonic-talking-to-oracle.html) for a sample configuration for SubSonic 2.x using ODP.NET or [here](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Setting_up_SubSonic_3.0) to see a screencast on configuring SubSonic 3.

Answer (score 0):

Scott,
Recently some developers have teamed-up to offer Oracle support (using Oracle's ODP.NET) for Subsonic 3.x, using the T4 Visual Studio template database provider system.  Please search Github.com for Oracle/Subsonic, or my link, http://github.com/mabraham1/LINQ2Oracle

Also, I've posted the template provider on the SubsonicProject site, as follows:
subsonicproject.com/docs/File:OracleTemplateProviderExample.RAR

Please rename the RAR to ZIP once downloaded (had trouble uploading a ZIP file).

Hope this helps!

Mark

Comment: Mark, where's the documentation for this? I downloaded it and could not figure out how to get up and running.

Comment: Aron, I'm no longer active in the SubSonic forums, since I've chosen to go with DevARt's DotConnect.  I would suggest looking for Simon Timm's branch:
git://github.com/stimms/SubSonic-3.0.git