# subsonic 3 oracle

Tags: oracle, subsonic, subsonic3

I have a couple of question's regarding the following project.

> *Scott, Recently some developers have teamed-up to offer Oracle support
> (using Oracle's ODP.NET) for Subsonic
> 3.x, using the T4 Visual Studio template database provider system.
> Please search Github.com for
> Oracle/Subsonic, or my link,
> http://github.com/mabraham1/LINQ2Oracle
>
> http://subsonicproject.com/docs/File:OracleTemplateProviderExample.RAR
> *

Has this stuff been tested and considered stable?  I notice that there is a comment on the subsonic website that states this is a work in progress.

The comments for the ORacle templates also state an Oracle flavored version of SS3 is needed.  What does that mean exactly?  Coming from 2.2 I just use different connection configurations for both.  I have data in both Oracle and sql, which has kept me in version 2.2.

Thanks -Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where the quote you have above comes from, if it's in the docs can you point me to the page as I've recently been trying to clarify this. The best summary of where the templates are is probably the following thread on the google group for subsonic:

http://groups.google.com/group/subsonicproject/browse_thread/thread/ed87958c9cbafb59/1745f6a8b6904657?lnk=gst&q=oracle#1745f6a8b6904657

But I think Jeff V summarises the current state as follows:

> "I was about to start 'dog-food'ing
>   our progress with a real-life
>   application. Up to this point I had
>   just been (trying) to run everything
>   through unit tests.  Hopefully using
>   it in a real app will bring to light
>   some more issues to fix up.  So I
>   wouldn't say its 100% yet, but we're
>   working on it, and it should be fairly
>   usable."

You can get the latest version of the Oracle templates from:

http://github.com/stimms/SubSonic-3.0-Templates/tree/master/TemplateProviders/

If you come across any issues please send them to the google group, the guys who are making it happen are Simon Timms, Jeff V and Mark Abraham.

Comment: I received the information here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262268/subsonic-support-for-oracle-odp-net

It appears that this might be what I need.